# Where is to download a sample iPhone application source code written by Swift, the new language?

Tags: swift

Does anyone know where to find a seed project written in Swift that I can use for learning?
So far, I have not been successful building or deploying any swift projects.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: No one besides Apple could have deployed a Swift app, as the software and language are not public yet.  You can successfully build one, though, and there are tutorials everywhere on the internet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you mean deploy as in the App Store, you still can not do that since Xcode 6 and Swift are still in beta.  However, if you want to see an app running in swift, you will need to follow a tutorial on the web.  A good one is from [Ray Wenderlich](http://www.raywenderlich.com/75270/make-game-like-candy-crush-with-swift-tutorial-part-1), and lets you program a game like candy crush all in swift, its a great way to see all the new code work.  Hope this helps.

Edit #1

If you are looking for something a bit easier you might want to take a look at Apple's book about swift.  It shows how to write the code and gives you samples and experiments to try.  Here is a [link](https://itunes.apple.com/us/book/swift-programming-language/id881256329?mt=11) to the book.  And [here](http://www.swiftcast.tv/articles/swift-programming-language-solutions-experiments) is a link to a website that posted all the answers to Apple's experiments in the book.

Comment: Thank you. Is there any simpler apps? I would like to build a basic one page app with database driven texts.